# How to fix ordered list sequence of database in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-database

I create a project that displays the first and last name of the user and email if users goes to the "/users". it is working fine but the issue is I am getting same number in the ordered list when I try to display the data. Kindly refer to the image for details. 
[dj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TARuQ.png)

Here is the code for the HTML file... How do I fix this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>User Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/usercss.css' %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h2>Welcome to user page</h2>
   {% if accessdata %}
   <ol>
   {% for elements in accessdata %}
    <li>UserProfile</li>
    <ul>
      <li> {{ elements.firstname }}</li>
      <li> {{ elements.lastname  }}</li>
      <li> {{ elements.email }}</li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
  {% else %}
   <p> No users found</p>
  {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are doing a `<ul>` directly inside the `<ol>`.
So the reason why the number `4` is occuring from the second list item on is that inside your `ul` you have 3 `li`-elements.

If you try the following you should get the correct numbering:

```html
<li>
  UserProfile
  <br />
  <ul>
    ...
  </ul>
</li>
```